# getting python in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I've already installed python3 on my computer.
when I started a new Jupyter notebook I selected python 3
but now on the notebook, it is saying it isn't there

when I run this:
print(python_version())

### i get this error:

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 print(python_version())

NameError: name 'python_version' is not defined

Comment: Try doing `import sys; print(sys.version)`

Comment: You need to specify the question to be useful

Answer (score 0):

`python_version()` function is from `platform` module; So you have to import it first:

```
import platform
print(platform.python_version())
```

Another way to check python version is `sys` module:

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```